# How to set row names while creating an object?

Tags: r

Is there any option in base R, how to set the row and columns names, i. e. dimension names *while creating an object* in base R?

**Example:**

Assuming we have a data frame 'dfe'.

```
set.seed(8803)
dfe <- data.frame(V1=sample(1:10, 3),
                  V2=sample(1:10, 3),
                  V3=sample(1:10, 3), 
                  V4=sample(1:10, 3))
dfe
#   V1 V2 V3 V4
# 1  3  7  1  6
# 2  9  4  6  5
# 3  5  2  8  9
```

We can set column names with `names(dfe) <- month.abb[1:4]` or (for data frames) `colnames(dfe) <- month.abb[1:4]`. Accordingly for the row names `rownames(dfe) <- LETTERS[1:3]`.

We also can do both in one process with `dimnames()`. Together with creating the data frame there are two steps though.

```
dfe <- data.frame(.)
dimnames(dfe) <- list(LETTERS[1:3], month.abb[1:4])
dfe
#   Jan Feb Mar Apr
# A   3   3   2   1
# B   9   4   6   9
# C  10   1   5   5
```

With `setNames()` we can give column names while creating the data frame.

```
dfe <- setNames(data.frame(V1=sample(1:10, 3),
                  V2=sample(1:10, 3),
                  V3=sample(1:10, 3), 
                  V4=sample(1:10, 3)), month.abb[1:4])
names(dfe)
# [1] "Jan" "Feb" "Mar" "Apr"
```

Have I missed something for the row names, even better dimension names in base R that sets these while creating an object? I couldn't find something like `setRowNames()` or `setDimNames()`. How do you do this?

***Note:* The solution should be rather be a general solution for objects than just fitting for creating data frames or matrices.**

Comment: The `data.frame` function has an option `row.names` where you can set the row names while creating the object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for both data frames and matrices.  Here `BOD` is a data frame that comes with R but this code also works if we replace `BOD` with `as.matrix(BOD)`

```
"rownames<-"(BOD, letters[1:6])
```

Comment: Would `"rownames<-"(setNames(data.frame(matrix(1:12, 3,4)), month.abb[2:5]), letters[4:6])` too cumbersome?

Comment: Similar functional form for `dimnames`: `\`dimnames<-\`(x = data.frame(v1 = 1:2, v2 = c("a", "b")), value = list(c("row1", "row2"), c("col1", "col2")))`